# Two lines, bottom and top, on the sides of an H2

Tags: html, css

So I have these two h2 elements.

XXXX

YYYY

And I want to achieve this on my index.html:

```
----------
          XXXXXX
                 ----------

----------
          YYYYYY
                 ----------
```

Two lines, on the sides, top and bottom. HTML5 and CSS.
I can do it for the 1st h2, however I0m not able to make it work for the second one. It'll get all scrambled.

```
.container2 {
width:100%;
}

.column {
width:33.33333333%;
float:left;
}


<div class="container2" style="margin-top:200px">
<div class="column" style="border-top: 1px solid black">
    <h2><span style="font-size:0.5em;"></span></h2>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <h2><span style="font-size:1.5em;" onclick="openNavVentas()">Ventas</span></h2>
</div>
<div class="column"  style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
    <h2><span style="font-size:0.5em;"></span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started I guess ...

```
<style>
  .test > * { width: 32%; display: inline-block; }
  .test > hr:nth-child(1) { margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  .test > hr:nth-child(3) { margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: -10px; }
</style>
<div class="test">
  <hr />
  <h2>XXXXXX</h2>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Example here ...
https://jsfiddle.net/rb9LsuLd/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "clear" the floats.

```
.container2 {
  width:100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dwv1qqch/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect by using a CSS `linear-gradient` as the `border-image`.

**Working Example:**

```css
h2 {
text-align:center;
margin-bottom: 48px;
padding: 12px;

border: 3px solid transparent;
border-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom right, 
    rgba(0,0,0,1) 19%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%,
    rgba(0,0,0,1) 81%);
border-image-slice: 1;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>First Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Second Heading 2</h2>
```